# How to store bash command as value of a key in a file, then read the file and execute the command using bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have created a bash script `test.sh` to check if some ports are listening or not. Since I dont want to hard-code either the ports or the command in the shell script, I put them both in a file `config_file` like key value pairs. Let me show the file and schell script below;

### test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cat config_file| while read port command; do
    if lsof -Pi :$port -sTCP:LISTEN -t >/dev/null ; then
        echo "" > /dev/null
    else
        eval "$command"
    fi
done
```

### config_file

```
80 /bin/bash /home/user/sample_script1.sh
22 /bin/bash /home/user/sample_script2.sh
```

Both files `sample_script1.sh` and `sample_script2.sh` are meant to `touch` some sample file. When I run `./test.sh` , the sample files gets created correctly (means `sample_script1.sh` and `sample_script2.sh` got invoked). But I get

```
./test.sh: line 8: This: command not found
```

in the terminal. What could be the reason and how to fix this?

Comment: See [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375).

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies some issues with the code.  The report includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Answer (score 2):

You could split the config file to another field, something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cat config.txt | {
  while read -r port shell command; do
    echo "$port"
    [[ -e "$shell" && -e "$command" ]] &&
    "$shell" "$command"
  done
}
```

---

It it is a file then you can do without the [UUOC](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/119), just use shell redirection, something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r port shell command; do
  echo "$port"
  [[ -e "$shell" && -e "$command" ]] &&
  "$shell" "$command"
done < config.txt
```

---

Or if the input is coming from a stream/command, something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r port shell command; do
  echo "$port"
  [[ -e "$shell" && -e "$command" ]] &&
  "$shell" "$command"
done < <(my_command_with_output)
```

---

- Make sure that there are no windows file ending aka carriage returns or some invisible characters from both files in question.